# Tracking errors in form with many functions

Tags: vb.net, function, error-handling, tracking

I have a winform that does a long procedure through many functions.

I want to create an arraylist and store the value "0" in it everytime a function works, and "-1" everytime a function doesn't. So I would be able to check it after the procedure is done and track the error in case one occured.

So I wrote this in my Try Catch:
(value is the value the function returns)

```
            Try
                'code here
            Catch ex As Exception
                ErrorArray.Add("-1")
            Finally
                If value <> Nothing Then
                    ErrorArray.Add("0")
                Else
                    ErrorArray.Add("-1")
                End If
            End Try
```

What is the smartest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the finally block does -- it might not be necessary.

It would be better to save some information so you'll know where the error occurred. Some possibilities:

1. Use multiple try-catch blocks.
2. Use a variable to tell where you're at in the function (not the best).
3. Record ex.message along with each error (should be done regardless).

I would use multiple try-catch blocks. If I didn't do that, I would save ex.message instead of -1 for each error, and use some kind of variable to save with ex.message to tell where the error occurred.

Comment: I actually went for all three. Used as many try catch blocks as I could, saved the ex.messages in text files, and filled an array with -1 in case of error and 0 in case of success then displayed it at the end of every process to notify me in case I had to check my Error folder for files.